# Where those sqlplus columns are used?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Just type col in sqlplus returns a list of columns, there are some columns ended with _recyc, where those columns are used ? I googled but could not find any documentation on them.

```
COLUMN   droptime_plus_show_recyc ON
HEADING  'DROP TIME'
FORMAT   a19

COLUMN   objtype_plus_show_recyc ON
HEADING  'OBJECT TYPE'
FORMAT   a12

COLUMN   objectname_plus_show_recyc ON
HEADING  'RECYCLEBIN NAME'
FORMAT   a30

COLUMN   origname_plus_show_recyc ON
HEADING  'ORIGINAL NAME'
FORMAT   a16
```

Comment: My guess: A deprecated piece of code best to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're used by the [`show recyclebin` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#sthref2276). If you run that you get headings like:

```
ORIGINAL NAME    RECYCLEBIN NAME                OBJECT TYPE  DROP TIME
---------------- ------------------------------ ------------ -------------------
...
```

If you do `clear columns` and run it again you get:

```
ORIGNAME_PLUS_SHOW_RECYC         OBJECTNAME_PLUS_SHOW_RECYC     OBJTYPE_PLUS_SHOW_RECYC   DROPTIME_PLUS_SHOW_
-------------------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------- -------------------
...
```

Whatever underlying query `show recyclebin` is using (some variant of `select .. from user_recyclebin` presumably) is aliasing the columns in the resultset; SQL*Plus is configured to format those aliased names.

The other pre-set column definitions are similar; for example, `show edition` gives a column displayed with heading `EDITION`, but if you `clear columns` it reverts to the underlying `NAME_COL_PLUS_SHOW_EDITION`. Anything with `_PLUS_SHOW_` is going to be for some output from a `show` command.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Another question is what object are kept in recyclebin when they are dropped ? I dropped an index of a table, I could not see it in recycle bin.

Comment: @user2018791 - an index will only be in [the recycle bin](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/tables011.htm) if it's dropped automatically by a table drop. You can't restore an index dropped independently - it would be out of step with its table, so would have to be rebuilt anyway. If a table is dropped, though, then restoring that can also restore the index as everything is still consistent.